# A program that calculates incentives of employees

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm new to python an am trying to create a program that would allow me to calculate the incentives of given employees based on their sales code. Each employee has a specific target to achieve. The target may be achieved or may not be. I have included the sales code and their corresponding target in an array which all line up to each other (the first element in salescode array has the target which is in the first element of the targets array). The achievement is inputted which is then divided by the target in the array based on the inputted sales code. this value is then given 4 if conditions to see what sort an incentive the individual gets.

The calculation I require is : percent=achievement/targets
How do I make it so that it calculates the above by traversing through the salescode and targets array (finding which one lines up in order to calculate it)?

```
salescode= [102,103,104,106,107,119,122,125,131,135,141,164,124,163,162]
targets=[3000000.00,4000000.00,3000000.00,3000000.00,3000000.00,4000000.00,2000000.00,2000000.00,2000000.00,3000000.00,2000000.00,3000000.00,2000000.00,2000000.00,2000000.00]

print(salescode)
print(targets)

sales=input("Enter\n")
achievement=input("Enter the Acheivement\n")

for sales in range(len(salescode)):
    percent=float(achievement)/float(targets)

    if  per>=2.50:
        print(" Incentive "+(float(achievement[x])*0.0225))
    elif  per>=2.00:
        print(" Incentive "+(float(achievement[x])*0.002))
    elif  per>=1.50:
        print(" Incentive "+(float(achievement[x])*0.0175))
    elif  per>=1.00:
        print(" Incentive "+(float(achievement[x])*0.001))
    elif  per<=0.99:
        print("Target Not Achieved")
```

---

Answer (score 1):

in salescode for loop you can get index and using this index you can get value of targets

```
salescode= [102,103,104,106,107,119,122,125,131,135,141,164,124,163,162]
targets=[3000000.00,4000000.00,3000000.00,3000000.00,3000000.00,4000000.00,2000000.00,2000000.00,2000000.00,3000000.00,2000000.00,3000000.00,2000000.00,2000000.00,2000000.00]

print(salescode)
print(targets)

sales=input("Enter\n")
achievement=input("Enter the Acheivement\n")

for sales in range(len(salescode)):
    getoutput =percetagefind(achievement,targets[sales])
    print(getoutput)
```

function

```py
def percetagefind(achievement,target):
    per=float(achievement)/float(target)

    if  per>=2.50:
        return (" Incentive "+(float(achievement[x])*0.0225)
    elif  per>=2.00:
        return (" Incentive "+(float(achievement[x])*0.002))
    elif  per>=1.50:
        return (" Incentive "+(float(achievement[x])*0.0175))
    elif  per>=1.00:
        return (" Incentive "+(float(achievement[x])*0.001))
    elif  per<=0.99:
        return ("Target Not Achieved")
```

Comment: Hi thanks that helped alot, by using index i can select the values. How do i make it so that it only selects the individual value and gives me a single output. Should I use an if function?

Comment: i change my answer you check it.

Comment: `zip` is your friend. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel